# unexpected behaviour: absolute positiong & $(window).resize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, window-resize

I am using a absolute positioned layout (a bit similar to pinterest)

So I need to recalculate positions also on window.resize: And as this event is not fired on dom ready, I do it manually.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize();
});
$(window).resize(setupBlocks);
```

Now, this function setupBlocks checks for the sizes of the HTML elements to calculate its new position

```
function setupBlocks() {
    if ($('.fancyContent').length > 0) {
        if ($('.rightFixed').length > 0) $('.fancyContent').width($(window).width() - 320)
        windowWidth = $('.fancyContent').width();
        //colWidth = $('.fancyContent .widgetHelp').outerWidth();
        blocks = [];
        //console.log(blocks);
        colCount = Math.floor(windowWidth / (colWidth + margin * 2));
        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            blocks.push(margin);
        }
        $('.fancyContent .widgetHelp').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'width': colWidth
        });
        positionBlocks();
        var topFooter = $('.fancyContent .widgetHelp:last').offset().top + 350;
        $('footer').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': topFooter
        });
        //console.log(topFooter);
        $('.fancyContent').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('#load').remove();
        //console.log($('#load').length);
    }
}

function positionBlocks() {
    $('.fancyContent .widgetHelp').each(function () {

        var min = Array.min(blocks);
        var index = $.inArray(min, blocks);
        var leftPos = margin + (index * (colWidth + margin));
        $(this).css({
            'left': leftPos + 'px',
            'top': min + 'px'
        });
        blocks[index] = min + $(this).outerHeight(true) + margin;
    });
}
```

The unexpected thing is that this is executed as expected. But the positions are not very well calculated untill the window is resized. Then the positions become exact.

I know it's a long shot. but any idea why it could be behaving differently?

Its better if you test yourself: `http://209.51.221.243/integracion/login.php`

When the page is load, the divs are almost fine (some of them are vertically touching), but if you resize the div the divs get well positioned. any thougths?

Comment: I didn't read through your code, but in this case, why don't you use css `position: fixed` positioning instead?

Comment: That won't fit the template. User would be seeing same posts even when scrollling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize();
});
```

`setupBlocks` function isn't called, this way it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('resize', setupBlocks); // window listens for resize events
    $(window).resize(); // fire window resize
});
```

Now you are sure your setup is run at page load [[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jT6ma/)].

Answer (score 0):

Rather than running the `$(window).resize()` on document ready, run it on window load. In other words change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize();
});
```

to

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(window).resize();
});
```

Since document ready just waits until all the DOM elements are in place, jQuery can't detect the proper block sizes and positions, because the images aren't loaded. Once the images load, dimensions change. If you want to get things positioned ASAP, try specifying heights and widths for the images, so when the document is ready (rather than the window loaded), jQuery can pick up on all the image sizes.

Comment: Hmmm - that's one more good theory shot down :( Seriously though, try changing `$(window).resize();` to the actual function you want to run: `setupBlocks();`.

Comment: same behavior. that's why i tried to fire the .resize() event, because when the real reize is performed, it just works fine :S